# Is there a Windows batch command that can copy files from a Linux server to my local machine?

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-transfer, scp

I have been using the following `scp` command:

```
SET cfolder=c:\temp\%currentdate%
scp -r username@servername.com:/opt/logs/test.log %cfolder%\test_K1B.log
```

The problem with the above is that it keeps asking for a password. Is there a way to automate this command without entering the username and/or password?

Since I am the only person running the commands and it will be on my local machine, I don't mind saving the username/password combo in a text file.

The other issue is that I don't have write access on the server. I can only read and copy files from it. Plus I don't want to mess around by logging onto the server.

My purpose is to set this up as an automated script that performs the file copy from the remote server to the temp directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation). WinSCP supports providing a password in its scripts (though it supports public key authentication as well).

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
    "get /remote/path/* C:\local\path\" ^
    "exit"
```

WinSCP GUI can [generate a batch file template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) like this for you.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: _(I'm the author of WinSCP)_ That's direct support. Great @MartinPrikryl !

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\ching\proj\fdGlIfFix\src\BP>pscp PS104T ching@moscow_host:/home/ching/tmp/
ching@moscow_host's password:
PS104T                    | 44 kB |  44.4 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%

C:\Users\ching\proj\fdGlIfFix\src\BP>pscp -i c:\users\ching\random.ppk PS104T ching@moscow_host:/home/ching/tmp/
PS104T                    | 44 kB |  44.4 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

Is this what you want?
Try PuTTY's pscp and its Key Generator at

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Provided having your remote server trusted your windows, i.e., have deployed the generated public key to your remote server, you specify the your private key instead of entering password.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked up ssh scp .. 'cos i'd heard scp was quite limited.

Try SFTP.

a link summarized from google says "SFTP is a file transfer protocol similar to FTP but uses the SSH protocol as the network protocol" and "SCP is only for transferring files, and can't do other things like list remote directories or removing files, which SFTP does do"

Well, SSH lets you log in automatically(see ssh-copy-id), so as long as you can SSH automatically you should be able to SFTP fine.

Comment: OpenSSH `sftp` behaves identically to `scp` in terms of authentication.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ok but do you agree with what that link says, that SFTP is better / does more like list remote directories and removing files?

Comment: Definitely. But OP asked for the password authentication. `sftp` does not help with that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl OP wants automatic log in, no password. SSH can do either password authentication or key-based. And SFTP is based on SSH so should be able to do either. Here for SFTP doing key-based authentication https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271695/sftp-automatic-login

Answer (score -1):

```
SET cfolder=c:\temp\%currentdate%

scp -p linuxpwd -r username@servername.com:/opt/logs/test.log %cfolder%\test_K1B.log
```

You can use this `-p` option to mention the password. It is not secure way but as you said you can do this.

Comment: There's no `-p password` switch in OpenSSH `scp`. `-p` means *"Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file."*